# Dialog box pops-up from background service Android

Tags: android, background, dialog

I wanted to know if its possable before I start my project.

I wanted my app running in the background and when i get a message through a dialog box will pop-up, Just like how the alarm app works on the android you set the alarm and when the alarm sounds it show you a picture of the alarm and you can snooze or stop it.

Is this possable to have this sort of alert in my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is very much possible. Create a broadcastreciever of your own and register it via android manifest file. Have your service send a broadcast to your broadcastreciever which will execute onRecieve method.

In your onRecieve you can do whatever you want. :)

Comment: Thanks, Am gonna do some research on broadcastreciever

Comment: It's really a vital component in android along with service, activity and other stuff.Android does use this internally a lot. For instance SMS app. developer.android.com is the one i always prefer to go first when i need some digging :)